# How can I create a States drop down?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

**Working with the Commerce example templates.**
The example template uses javascript to populate the States which is based on the selected Country. The code for the Country and State select field:

```
<div class="field plaintext {% if model and model.getErrors('countryId') | length %}has-error{% endif %}">
<label for="{{ modelName }}-countryId">Country</label>
<select class="address-country" name="{{ modelName }}[countryId]">
    {% for key, option in countries %}
        {% set optionValue = (model ? model.countryId : '') %}
        <option value="{{ key }}" {% if key == optionValue %} selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% if model and model.getErrors('countryId') %}
    <p class="errors">{{ model.getErrors('countryId')|join }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

```
<div class="field plaintext {% if model and model.getErrors('stateId') | length %}has-error{% endif %}">
<label for="{{ modelName }}-state">State</label>
{% set options = (model and states[model.countryId] is defined ? states[model.countryId] : []) %}
<select id="{{ modelName }}-stateId" data-modelname="{{ modelName }}" class="address-stateId {% if options|length == 0 or (model and model.stateName) %}hidden{% endif %}" name="{{ modelName }}[stateValue]">
    {% for key, option in options %}
        {% set optionValue = (model ? model.stateId : '') %}
        <option value="{{ key }}" {% if key == optionValue %}selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="text" data-modelname="{{ modelName }}" id="{{ modelName }}-stateName" class="address-stateName {% if options|length > 0 or (model and model.stateId) %}hidden{% endif %}" {% if model and model.stateName %}name="{{ modelName }}[stateValue]" value="{{ model.stateName}}"{% endif %}>
```

All I'm looking for is a drop down for US States no other Countries will be used. I like to keep the 'model' in place though.

The javascript:

```
{% includejs %}
var states = {{ craft.commerce.statesArray|json_encode|raw }};

$('select.address-country').change(function ()
{
    // get the value of the selected country.
    var cid = $(this).val();
    var $states = $(this).closest('.addressBox').find('select.address-stateId');
    var $stateName = $(this).closest('.addressBox').find('input.address-stateName');
    $states.find('option').remove();

    if (states.hasOwnProperty(cid))
    {
        // We have states for this country, show the states drop down.
        $states.removeClass('hidden');
        $states.attr('name', $states.data('modelname')+'[stateValue]');

        // We have states for this country, hide the stateName input.
        $stateName.removeAttr('name');
        $stateName.addClass('hidden');
        $stateName.val('');

        // Add all states as options to drop down.
        for (var id in states[cid])
        {
            var state = states[cid][id];
            var $option = $('<option/>');
            $option.attr('value', id).text(state);
            $states.append($option);
        }

    }else{
        // hide the states dropdown, since this country has none.
        //$states.addClass('hidden');
        //$states.removeAttr('name');

        // show the stateName
        $stateName.removeClass('hidden');
        $stateName.attr('name', $stateName.data('modelname')+'[stateValue]');
    }

});

$('select').addClass('form-control input-sm');{% endincludejs %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just hardcoding based on the US `countryId` of `233`.

`{% set states = craft.commerce.statesArray["233"] %}`

Then simplified my template like this:

```
<select name="{{ 'model' ~ '[stateId]' }}" required>
     {% for key, state in states %}
          <option value="{{key}}">{{state}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a spin. How can we check out the countryId's?

Comment: I just used twig's dump var to look at the array prior to hardcoding it. So `{{dump(states)}}`